# How to sort this Dictionary by sub key date time in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-3.6

I have tried all similar answers on Stack-overflow and none of them work for me. Because none of them have this data structure. Any help very much appreciated.

I have this working on python 2 but cant get it working on python 3.

This line of code works in python 2 but not in python 3.6

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Here is what the dictionary looks like. I have to sort on the Key 'updated'
i.e. `my_dict[key_one]['updated']`
(So basically I want the most recent date at the top)

```
my_dict={
        'key_one': {
            'sub_key_1': {
                'bla1': 0,
                'bla2': 5,
                'bla3': 'sdfsdf'
            },
            'SubKey2': {
                'bla1': 0,
                'bla2': 5,
            },
            'updated': '25-08-2020 14:53:56'
        },
        'key_two': {
            'sub_key_1': {
                'bla2': 0,
                'bla3': 5,
                'bla4': 'sdfsdf'
            },
            'SubKey2': {
                'bla1': 0,
                'bla2': 5,
            },
            'updated': '26-08-2020 14:53:56'
        },
        'key_three': {
            'sub_key_1': {
                'bla2': 0,
                'bla3': 5,
                'bla4': 'sdfsdf'
            },
            'SubKey2': {
                'bla1': 0,
                'bla2': 5,
            },
            'updated': '27-08-2020 14:53:56'
        }
    }
```

Comment: key should be: `lambda x: x[1]['updated']` to sort by dates.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments by @Gábor:

```
sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['updated'], reverse=True)
```

output:

```
[('key_three', {'sub_key_1': {'bla2': 0, 'bla3': 5, 'bla4': 'sdfsdf'}, 'SubKey2': {'bla1': 0, 'bla2': 5}, 'updated': '27-08-2020 14:53:56'}), ('key_two', {'sub_key_1': {'bla2': 0, 'bla3': 5, 'bla4': 'sdfsdf'}, 'SubKey2': {'bla1': 0, 'bla2': 5}, 'updated': '26-08-2020 14:53:56'}), ('key_one', {'sub_key_1': {'bla1': 0, 'bla2': 5, 'bla3': 'sdfsdf'}, 'SubKey2': {'bla1': 0, 'bla2': 5}, 'updated': '25-08-2020 14:53:56'})]
```